# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger in generated jar file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I generated a `jar` file with `Maven` in IntelliJ IDEA. I get following error message when try to execute it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/log4j/Logger

I use only one `log4j` version, 1.2.17 and java version 1.8.0_171. I set skip tests in pom.xml too: `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>`
Execution is successful directly from IDE. I use Maven Surefire plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: have you added jars with dependencies into classpath when executing your jar?

Comment: Are you trying to execute your Java program from the command line? Could you add the command you invoke?

Comment: @Daniele : I got following error, when try to execute with `java -jar <myjar>` : no main manifest attribute

Comment: you can fix the "no main manifest attribute" issue by using @streetturtle 's suggestion below. (the manifest will be added to the jar generated by `mvn package`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it from IDEA dependencies are included by IDEA, you can check the command in **Run** Tool Window of IDEA.
But when you generate a jar and run it there is no dependencies included in it. To make it work you have to tell Maven to include them, one of the way to do it is to use [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) by adding `build` section to your **pom.xml**:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>package.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I added it, but it generated a 30 KB jar and got the same error.